# Simple example to send data with lora on mDot

Tags: mbed, lora, lorawan

I have multitech conduit set up as packet forwarder to resiot platform and I would like the simplest example to send data via loraWAN with multitech mdot (mbed platform). I have problems with compiling dot examples, and cannot find any documentation for library so a simple example would clarify a lot for me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work? https://docs.mbed.com/docs/lora-with-mbed/en/latest/intro-to-lora/

Some tips:

- Use the same mbed-os version as noted in libmdot commit message.
- Use Dot-Examples which is compatible with the libmdot you're using (probably v3).

Comment: I just need an example code, I have looked at dot examples but cannot understand them completly. 
What I would like is somones working code if there are any projects open source or a simple example like:

variable = some value
setup for lora (appeui, appkey,..)
send value of variable

Comment: Take a look at [arm-ttn-webinar's main.cpp](https://github.com/johanstokking/arm-ttn-webinar/blob/master/src/main.cpp). It runs both on xDot and mDot and sets up the keys (in ttn_config.h), and sends some data. It's not gonna be easier than this unfortunately. If you want to have more background, check [this webinar](https://pages.arm.com/Webinar-OnDemand-Getting-started-with-LoRa.html) which uses the repo to connect a Dot to The Things Network.

Comment: Thank you, that code is simple enough! Examples privided by multitech have too many unnecessary stuff so it is hard to isolate important lines of code. Thank you again!